# How to continously map an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create an alert component in React.JS which would receive one array as props and then loop through all the elements inside and display them in the alert component.

I do not know how to restart the loop when the array map ends.

This is my code:

```
        useEffect(() => {
                props.messages.map((item, index) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                          setMessage(item);
                        }, 5000*index)
                      });
        },[]);
```

I want to run the loop continuously until the user closes the notification alert.

My guess is to wrap the map inside a while / do while in order to run it until the user closes the notification bar. I am having trouble restarting the loop once the map of the array gets to the last element.

Comment: That's not how you're meant to use `Array.prototype.map`. You shouldn't use `map` at all in this case, actually.

Comment: Are you *basically* just wanting to increment an array index, or rather, grab an element from an array to update state, on an interval? Your question is unclear and you haven't provided enough code or context for us to help.

Comment: i want to increment an array index. I know I could do a for loop and once the index has the same value as the array length, then initialize the index to the starting value (0).

Comment: I would recommend to use multiple instances of Alert with z-index. so that they overlap or stack on top of each other. You can create a service, which will clear the stack based on the timeout or leave it when it close on action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to compute an index and reset back to zero.

Add an `index` state and mounting `useEffect` hook to increment the index on the 5 second interval. Don't forget to return a cleanup function to clear the interval timer.

```
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const timerRef = setInterval(() => {
    setIndex(i => i + 1);
  }, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(timerRef);
},[]);
```

Use a second `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `index` state. When it updates take the `index` modulus the array length to compute a valid in-range index and update the current `message` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const { messages } = props;
  setMessage(messages[index % messages.length]);
}, [index]);
```

However, the second `useEffect` hook and `message` state isn't necessary, and could be considered derived state. *Derived from the `props.messages` array and current `index` state.* You can simply use these directly in the rendered alert.

Example:

```
<Alert message={messages[index % messages.length]} />
```